# Asp.Net MVC Core 3.0 - Identity Framework

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

**Requirements**

I'd like to implement the Asp.Net Identity Framework, into an Asp.Net **MVC** Core 3.0 application.

The only examples I can find online are for pure [Asp.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) (not the MVC version).

Any suggestions on where I can find *the examples that are for MVC*, specifically?

**Stack**

- C# Asp.Net **MVC** Core 3.0
- Identity Framework

**UPDATE**

I've now implemented the code, following the comments below.

How do I amend the code to create a fresh database, as opposed to using migrations?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace IdentityDemo.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Identity is independent of the framework you use to model your site. There's no such thing as `MVC Identity`. The link you provided is what you would use to implement into an MVC project.

Comment: Understood - I am particularly interested in seeing which code goes into controllers, versus Startup.cs configuration (as opposed to Pages, as in pure Asp.Net Core without MVC).

Comment: Again, the link you have posted is how you would configure it with MVC. The difference being, rather than sticking `[Authorize]` on your razor page, you stick it on your controller? Literally just substitute a razor page with a controller.

Comment: @KieranDevlin Perfect, thanks Kieran!

Comment: @KieranDevlin Please see update section above. Thanks